# Electon setBadgeCount equivalent for GTK apps

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gtkmm

I discovered that electron app can use the `app.setBadgeCount` method to get badge icons. For example in teams:

[image]

https://www.electronjs.org/fr/docs/latest/api/app#appsetbadgecountcount-linux-macos

I'm looking for something equivalent for linux GTK apps (using gtkmm), but I can't find any information. It must exist, right?